# Playframework: Upgrade process -- Best Practices

Tags: process, upgrade, playframework

I'd very much appreciate anyone sharing best-practices, patterns, anti-patterns, backup, rollback processes that you have formulated for a pain-free, foolproof, Play framework upgrade.

I'm thinking just replacing the bin/play directory with the latest version can cause problems

Edit:

I'm looking for more specific version management strategies, say,

a) Do you just have /bin/play directory having the latest play version or 
b) Do you keep versions like /bin/play-1.1 /bin/play-1.2 and change your $PATH to point to the latest (cons: you have to rebuild your modules, dependencies & libs; pros: gives better control over rollback)

Comment: Have you tried just upgrading?  It may work fine.  Make sure you have backups though.

Comment: I have upgraded apps from 1.0.3.2 to 1.1 and then 1.2 without any issue. It becomes more complicated the more modules you have, but the base code I have not had any issues with.

Comment: I run my development on Windows 7, and have each version of Play installed in c:\play\play-1.1 c:\play\play-1.2\ etc. I then have a command line shortcut that runs a batch file on start, which sets the path to the relevant version. I don't use a great deal of modules or dependencies, so this is not usually an issue for me either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer to install play from source using git:

```
git clone git://github.com/playframework/play.git
cd play

# checkout specific version
git checkout 1.2.1

cd framework
ant
cd ..
ln -s $PWD/play ~/bin
```

So I have a full install including all source. Later, when play was updated to version 1.2.2 I did the following:

```
cd <play_home>
git pull
git checkout 1.2.2
cd framework
ant
```

In your application you then do

```
play clean && play run
```

The advantage of running play from a source build is that you can always and easily roll back to the previous version or even test out features from current development. This does not solve the problem of having multiple versions of play active at the same time though.

Comment: Thanks Andre. This is great. Looking for a couple more best practices (around database and other peripheral areas) before I close this question

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Andre. However, if you are asking for best practice for a live project, I would do it differently.

You can have multiple version installed on your local machine. The only thing you have to change is which one is visible in the path. For instance you could have 1.1, 1.2, 2.0 and depending on which one you want, you just modify your `/home/youruser/.bashrc` file.

The reason, why simple update of play from `git` or `hg` will not work/good idea is because, incase there are problems, you have to revert, rollback modules, or goodness know what not.

It is far better to simple swap out the play version, rebuild, test extensively, once you are ok that everything is good, then you can make the same changes in a live site.

If things don't workout, or your are hopelessly lost, all you have to do is revert the changes to your project and switch the play version. You will be back to where you started.